# How to learn using my dataset on deeplab v3 plus

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

In deeplab v3p, although I trained my data sets, it did not work.
Why is it?

**My environment is the bellow:**

```
OS Platform and Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04 lts
TensorFlow installed from: conda
TensorFlow version: 18
Bazel version: no
CUDA/cuDNN version: cuda 9 cudnn 7
GPU model and memory: titan x (2 cards), 64gb memory
Exact command to reproduce: -
```

I did the following work:

**a) generate simple dataset:**

The training image arranges two figures (circle and rect) randomly and draws color randomly.
The label image is set to 0RGB(0, 0, 0) for the background, 1 RGB (1,1,1) for the rect, 2RGB(2, 2, 2) for the circle and 255 RGB (255, 255, 255) for the line as the segmentation.

https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/2be21942628a85c46fd8ffb99e05b257b4b0c980/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f39353633362f62653262306638632d333933322d363434322d336132342d6534306333613466653865612e706e67

https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/323d4f21d792138ebb52f994dc42cc0b5d3ab30d/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f39353633362f34656633633261332d633533372d316134632d653633342d3165663632643734623166392e706e67

**b) convert to tf.record**

In the `build_voc2012_data.py`, I changed file path from origin datasets to my datasets.
Then, I ran it and created tf.record.

**c) training**

In the `segmentation_dataset.py`, I added DATASETS INFORMATION.

```
_MYDATASETS_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 10000,
        'trainval': 1000,
        'val': 1000,
    },
    num_classes=3,
    ignore_label=255,
)


 _DATASETS_INFORMATION = {
     'cityscapes': _CITYSCAPES_INFORMATION,
     'pascal_voc_seg': _PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION,
     'ade20k': _ADE20K_INFORMATION,
     'mydata': _MYDATASETS_INFORMATION
 }
```

Then, I started training.

```
python train.py   --logtostderr   --train_split=trainval   --model_variant=xception_65   --atrous_rates=6   --atrous_rates=12   --atrous_rates=18   --output_stride=16   --decoder_output_stride=4   --train_crop_size=513   --train_crop_size=513   --train_batch_size=4   --training_number_of_steps=1000000   --fine_tune_batch_norm=true   --tf_initial_checkpoint="./datasets/y/model.ckpt"  --train_logdir="./datasets/x"  --dataset_dir="./datasets/z/tfrecord" --dataset=mydata
```

**d) finished training**

As a result of one million iterations, the minimum loss was 4.765.
When it started trainning, it was 7.56.

**e) VIS.**
two of the test images.

input image: https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/e37afb4ae0e5232a0c0828dad779a4a852462a45/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f39353633362f64363930326231622d386164302d306366612d656433642d6436346537383462636134322e706e67

output image:
https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/d638a2fc7fe5f5119e2f00d7c0aa59b9b8fc73d4/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f39353633362f36643963643265372d373234362d636434612d303566322d6335623266396237623865352e706e67

input image: https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/8fe89aa43aac3a322ede1ac46d469fc48da6b809/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f39353633362f64313162643834372d323734372d643530642d393366642d6231353661353137613934632e706e67

output image:
https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/94f15de43ce6195bdc8602b800d1275a4830193c/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f39353633362f63623061666663652d613566302d363333302d306362382d6261393964363735333734652e706e67

From the above results, I think that Deeplab v3 does not work well.
Is my usage wrong? Or is the parameter setting incorrect?
Or is the learning not enough?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your training batch size (`--train_batch_size=4`) is too small. You need to have a larger batch size.

See 
[Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network) to get a better idea on choosing a more accurate value.